# Listing publications for a non-tenure track teaching job?

Tags: publications, phd, teaching, cv

I do not have a stellar first authored publication record as I am finishing towards earning a PhD in environmental science. I do have several conference abstracts and a few coauthored publications, however. I came across a non-tenure track academic job that is purely focused on teaching elementary environment science courses with an additional academic management role. Assuming the search committee is primarily interested in my teaching experiences, is it worthwhile to list my publications/proceedings in my CV? What are the pros and cons? My fear is that the search committee might flag me as a candidate who is occupying the position temporarily (they are looking for someone permanent) based on publications/research interests. I am genuinely interested in the job to gain teaching experience no matter how much I love doing research. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PhD is a research degree. To earn it you need to publish, even if just the thesis, that is considered a publication. If the job requires a doctorate then they are explicitly asking for trained researchers who want to switch to teaching. They consider it valuable to the job, presumably. And it probably is.

Either way though, your CV should include everything you've done. It does not have to be tailored to a job. You do that with your cover letter, and research/teaching statements if you want. At least you will show, that while you weren't getting specifically-applicable experience, you're a productive worker who will devote yourself to whatever you do.

Teaching positions at universities and colleges are also typically very competitive, and you will have a disadvantage versus those who already have teaching experience. You need to highlight everything that helps you. Including your research. For example note how you would like to leverage your research experience in your coursework in some way, such as help provide motivation or course projects. You need to give this kind of thing a lot of thought and show that you have done so. Consider the specific courses and the syllabus you would create (perhaps create some materials to show them). This will help even if they will provide you with materials to use.